# How to remove empty URL value parameter with HTACCESS

Tags: forms, .htaccess, url, get, url-parameters

Hi i want to remove the empty URL value parameter with HTACCESS. Right now i've managed to get http://localhost/TEST/formpage?model=tshirt&color=&size= to just http://localhost/TEST/formpage?model=tshirt. But when i add the third value of size and emptied the second value of color, it won't work. So when i input model=tshirt color='empty' and size=S, it just shows http://localhost/TEST/formpage?model=tshirt. How can i get it worked ? in the future there will be another value not just 3. Here is my current code

```
<form method="get" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="model" id="model" /> 
    <input type="text" name="color" id="color" /> 
    <input type="text" name="size" id="size" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="sumbit" />
</form>
```

And the Htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/formpage\/?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(&|\?)[a-z-_]+=(?=&|$)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* \/TEST/formpage?%1%2 [R,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do mention more clearly **FROM** which URL **TO** which url you want to redirect? Just post samples in your question and that will make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to fix this using URL rewriting? If you do not need to fix any requests coming from external links, but only what your form submission URLs will look like - then I would probably do this using JS on the client side. Add a submit handler to the form, loop over the input fields - and set those with an empty value to `disabled`, then they don't become part of the form submission data set to begin with.

Comment: it is going to the same URL or page @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Has this problem been solved?

Comment: @anubhava yes it has, but using different method but just as simple